# Where accessing swap space is handled in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory-management, linux-kernel, swapfile

**I am working as research assistant and this question is really vital for our group:**

We are looking for a way to inject delays when a process (i.e. a python program) is using swap space. For example, if in a normal way, it is swapping-in pages from swap space to main memory to work on it, we need to make a delay before that. (I know it doesn't make sense in real world to make delay in kernel when accessing swap space or main memory, but with doing that we will be able to simulate something which is important for us to do so.)

**What I did before:**

I already tried adding a `printk` statement to the following sections in the kernel but none of them seem to be the exact location of handling `swap-in` and `swap-out` for a process.

1. In the `memory.c` file, in the function `do_swap_page()`. It didn't work always.
2. In the `memcontrol.c` file, in the function `mem_cgroup_swapin_charge_page`. It just works when the application is newly allocating the swap space. (And not whenever it is using the swap actually)
3. In the `swap_state.c` file, in the function `swapin_readahead()` and also in the function `swap_vma_readahead()`. None of them works even when the process is using swap space.

Note 1: I am using the latest version of kernel (6.0.9). But I don't think it will be different with different versions of Linux kernel.
Note 2: I am measuring the amount of swap used with the command `free -m`. Also, more information is available in the `/proc/meminfo` file. So, I am sure that my process is using swap space, but I don't know how to catch it in the kernel sorce code.

It has been weeks that I a looking for an answer but no success. Any help is so appretiated. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look into `swap_readpage()` in `mm/page_io.c`

Comment: Note: you can select swap device and swap file. Depending on what you are looking, you may be able to slow swap indirectly (at device level and not modifying kernel).

Comment: Create a new, simple block device driver that just adds a delay to the underlying real block device. Then use it for swap.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks for your answer, can you provide a code for doing that? I am not familiar with how to create a "device".

Comment: @stark thanks for your answer, can you provide a code for doing that? I am not familiar with how to create a "device" driver and add delay there.

Comment: @dimich Thank you very much. I tried that file, and it seems that it is working. I need to have different tests for it to make sure. Do you have any references for it? (I need to have a reference for research work)